# Python - Loop through directory and call function on each file

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to loop through a directory and call a function on each file that ends with the initials of a person, found in a list.

The file name looks like this:

TimeSheet_EBSC_FraTeam_BIE.xlsx

or

TimeSheet_EBSC_FraTeam_BIE.xlsm

My code gets me in the right directory, and runs the code, but only for the first person in the list and stops after that. It doesn't move on to the next one.

Here is the code I have:

(In this case, both files containing these initials are .xlsx)

```
def find_initials():
    os.chdir("J://EBSC//1_EBSC//3_Employee matters//1_Timesheets")
    EBSC = ["BIE", "IWA"]

    for person in EBSC:
        for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
            if i.endswith(person+".xlsx") or i.endswith(person+".xlsm"):
                find_errors(person)
```

Comment: What's in `find_errors` function? And how exactly does it stop, with an exception?

Comment: Add print statements to see where you get stuck. Especially around the find_error function.

Comment: The find_errors is pretty long so I won't post it here. But it looks for errors in a file. At the end of the function it prints them in a .txt file and closes that file. The last statement is 'text_file.close()'

Comment: Have you checked the file? Anything written in it? Or can you please add `text_file.write("something")` right before function ends just for debugging purposes.

Comment: Everything prints in the file just the way I want it to...

Comment: Have you checked what `os.listdir(os.getcwd())` returns? And by any chance does your `find_errors()` uses `os.chdir()`?

Comment: @PierreCorbin if everything prints the way you want, what is the problem :D

Comment: I found the solution. I was changing directory in find_errors() and not changing back to where I needed to be in the loop of find_initials().
Thanks @Lafexlos for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

whether or not find_errors() function has errors or exceptions, you can try print statements before and  after find-errors() call.
Like:
print "hi"
find_errors(person)
print "hello"

If hi and hello both get printed for every entry in loop then we can assume find_errors() is working fine.

Thanks,